# window Azure service on compute emulator

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-worker-roles

I made a Windows Azure project as **Worker Role**..which has a simple WCF service.
When I run it on my local system then **Compute Emulator** give me following error...

I installed latest Azure SDK toolkit. Kindly tell me why this error occurs.

```
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.ControlChannel.GetControlContainer()
[Diagnostics]: Acquired mutex  
[Diagnostics] Information: C:\Users\kashif\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\85b2b7f8-61ec-499d-a473-b39674855c21\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor    
[Diagnostics] Information: C:\Users\kashif\Downloads\WCFWorkerRole\WCFWorkerRole\WCFWorkerRole\csx\Debug\roles\WCFWorker\diagnostics\x64\monitor\MonAgentHost.exe -LocalPath "C:\Users\kashif\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\85b2b7f8-61ec-499d-a473-b39674855c21\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor" -StaticConfigFile  "C:\Users\kashif\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\85b2b7f8-61ec-499d-a473-b39674855c21\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor\Configuration\mastaticconfig.xml" -ConfigFile "C:\Users\kashif\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\85b2b7f8-61ec-499d-a473-b39674855c21\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor\Configuration\maconfig.xml" -ShutDownEvent WADDM-ShutDown-f615698470fe491ea136287908faa42c -InitializedEvent WADM-StartUp-f615698470fe491ea136287908faa42c -parent 11516 -events
[MonAgentHost] Output: Agent will exit when WADDM-ShutDown-f615698470fe491ea136287908faa42c is signaled.    
[MonAgentHost] Output: Will signal WADM-StartUp-f615698470fe491ea136287908faa42c after the agent is initialized.       
[MonAgentHost] Output: Registered as an event consumer.    
[MonAgentHost] Output: Agent will exit when parent process 11516 exits.    
[MonAgentHost] Output: Monitoring Agent Started    
[Diagnostics]: Creating config channel server    
[Diagnostics]: Starting configuration channel polling    
[runtime] Role entrypoint . COMPLETED OnStart()    
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   Run()    
Information: WCFWorker entry point called    
Information: Working    
Information: Working    
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2012-06-04T13:40:32.487Z    
[MonAgentHost] Error:      2    
[MonAgentHost] Error:      11292    
[MonAgentHost] Error:      7264    
[MonAgentHost] Error:      NetTransport    
[MonAgentHost] Error:      0    
[MonAgentHost] Error:  x:\btsdx\215\services\monitoring\shared\nettransport\src\netutils.cpp    
[MonAgentHost] Error:      OpenHttpSession    
[MonAgentHost] Error:      749    
[MonAgentHost] Error:      0    
[MonAgentHost] Error:      2f94    
[MonAgentHost] Error:    
[MonAgentHost] Error:      WinHttpGetProxyForUrl(http://127.0.0.1) failed ERROR_WINHTTP_AUTODETECTION_FAILED (12180)    
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2012-06-04T13:40:32.504Z    
[MonAgentHost] Error:      2    
[MonAgentHost] Error:      11292    
[MonAgentHost] Error:      7264    
[MonAgentHost] Error:      NetTransport    
[MonAgentHost] Error:      0    
[MonAgentHost] Error: x:\btsdx\215\services\monitoring\shared\nettransport\src\xblobconnection.cpp    
[MonAgentHost] Error:      XBlobConnection::SendBytesRequestAndGetHttpStatus    
[MonAgentHost] Error:      1980    
[MonAgentHost] Error:      ffffffff80050006
```

#### Worker role OnStart:

```cs
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12; 
ServiceHost host; 
IPEndPoint ip = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["port"].IPEndpoint; 
Uri baseAddress = new Uri(String.Format("http://{0}/MyService", ip)); 
try { host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MessengerService), baseAddress); host.Open(); }
catch (Exception ex) { Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message, "Error"); throw; } 
return base.OnStart();
```

Comment: You should probably share your worker role / WCF code for context.

Comment: Please add your code to the OP (question), *not as a comment*.

Comment: what is OP?.. because there is no option other than comment

Comment: No worries...you haven't [earned the privilege to edit questions](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) yet - I've added it for you. (**OP = original post**)

Comment: how to increase my reputation on stack overflow because i am new on stacoverflow

Comment: See the [SO FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation).

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of this, you need to disable the “Automatically detect settings” option in the Control Panel -> Network and Internet -> Internet Options -> Connections -> LAN Settings.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time this exception is directly related with your Azure Development Storage startup process. And there could be several reasons why you could not start Azure Development Storage. Azure Development Storage has dependency on local SQL Server Express components so sometime any problem related with your SQL Server components could cause this problem.

To ensure that your Azure Development Storage is running, try launching C:\Program Files\Windows Azure Emulator\emulator\csmonitor.exe  in admin mode and then verify that you can run both compute Emulator and Development Storage manually.

Once above test goes without any problem, test your Worker Role + WCF application, this should let you go without any problem and if you still see the problem when Azure Storage is running fine, please show your worker role onStart() code. (I would also suggest to just create a very simple web or worker role hello world sample to see if that give you any error. This will prove if you have any issue with your SDK installation or not)

**Added More:**

Error message your provided as "[MonAgentHost] Error:      WinHttpGetProxyForUrl(http://127.0.0.1) failed ERROR_WINHTTP_AUTODETECTION_FAILED (12180)
" are benign as described in my [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/01/20/winhttpgetproxyforurl-failed-error-winhttp-autodetection-failed-12180-error-message-in-windows-azure-infrastructure-log.aspx).

Next based on your above code (and the sample link) I really don't see any exception which shows the error:

Have you tried using accessing services:

```
http://{0}/MyService
it would be http://127.0.0.1:9001/MyService if you have followed the sample code provided in the link?
```

Also your OnStart() function is far more different then the one in the link you provided, I hope you know what are you doing in your code because the info you provided above is quite different then so unless you know what you are doing, it best to follow the article completely to match the results.

Comment: My Compute Emulator and storage is running properly.. but still it gives same error... my service is very simple just like helloWorld

Comment: i run this example...

http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/5061-azure-part-37---windows-azure-%C2%96-wcf-worker.aspx